# How to update child records in the store when parent record is saved?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin`.

When i initially fetch a parent record containing child records from the server, child records automatically populate the store. I don't need to create child records manually.

But when i subsequently save a parent record, dirty child records remain dirty, and it seems that i have to update them manually.

Here's a demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vaniyo/2/edit?html,js,output

After editing a child's name and saving the parent, i expect the dirty child to update and become non-dirty.

**Question 1**: shouldn't `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin` take care of that?

**Question 2**: how do i have my child records updated to a non-dirty state when i save a parent record?

Comment: Yes bug, and you could hack it into the adapter.

Comment: Hey @Kingpin2k, can you please show how i can hack into the adapter? I've found one way in Ember Data issue queue, but it's so lowlevel that i'm afraid to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue for me and published the solution as an Ember CLI addon: https://github.com/lolmaus/ember-cli-stained-by-children

If it helps you, please star it.

Comment: `EmbeddedRecordsMixin` is weird, it does not take care of nested models. I saw what you did there for manually invoke `hasDirtyAttributes` down to its children model. Thank you.

Comment: @AlanDong Note that the addon has been abandoned and is not compatible with the modern version of Ember Data. There's a branch that supports modern ED, but it's not production-ready and I'm not actively developing it.